Dirac Delta Measure on Random Variable
I am confused about  $\mu_n =\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{X_i}}{n}$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d random variables.
My understanding is that,
$\mu_{n}(A) = \frac{1}{n} \delta_{X_i}(A)=\frac{ \text{number of i such that} X_i \in A}{n} $
But $X_i$ depends on $\omega$, thus should I be interpreting this as given the realizations of the $n$ random variables, $\mu_{n}$ is as defined?

Yes. $\mu_n$ is a "random measure", and is itself a function of the random variables $X_i$. For measurable $A$, $\mu_n(A)$ is a real-valued random variable, counting the proportion of $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ which fall in the set $A$. If the random variables $X_i$ take values in a set $E$, then you can think of $\mu_n$ as a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to the set of probability measures on $E$.

@abomasnow No, it's very standard notation. The point is to consider $\delta_{x_0}$ not for $x_0\in\Omega$, but for $x_0\in E$ where $E$ is the range (or codomain) of the random variables $X_i$. As usual this doesn't involve needing to know anything about the structure of the sample space $\Omega$. One doesn't need $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ or $\Omega=E$ or any such thing.

@abomasnow There is no need to worry at all. It isn't some loose notation, it's completely precise. The definition of the delta measure is as follows: given a set $E$, a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{E}$ on $E$,  and a point $x_0\in E$, the Dirac measure $\delta_{x_0}$ is the measure on $(E, \mathcal{E})$ defined by $\delta_{x_0}(A)=1$ if $x_0\in A$ and $\delta_{x_0}(A)=0$ if $x_0\notin A$, for  $A\in \mathcal{E}$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure
